# TYPO3 TCA select with own items

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I use TYPO3 version 9. 
I am trying to configure TCA selectMultipleSideBySide. I want to use without foreign table, I want to pass my own items. It displays correctly, but when I try to add more then 1 item, I get error:

These fields of record 3 in table "tx_scout24_domain_model_vehicle" have not been saved correctly: equipment! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database.

It because TYPO3 try to save data to main table, but not in mm table.
My current TCA:

```
    'equipment' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:scout24/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:equipment',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'items' => \Istar\Scout24\Service\FieldService::getFields('equipment'),
            'MM' => 'tx_scout24_vehicle_equipment_mm',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/#a-multiple-value-selector-with-contents-from-a-database-table) the values are stored as comma-separated values. It is not possible to use a MM relation table. To store the values the columns must be of type varchar. Because you can store one value it seems that the type of your columns is an int, which can be stored without a problem.

So you have to do:

- Remove the MM relation in your configuration
- Change your table column to varchar